# Is Azure CloudTable thread-safe?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm writing to Azure Table storage using Storage SDK 2.0 from different threads (ASP.NET application).

Is **CloudTable** object **thread-safe**? Can I initialize CloudStorageAccount, CloudTableClient and CloudTable only once (for example, in static constuctor) and then use them in different threads?

Or is it better to create all CloudStorageAccount, CloudTableClient and CloudTable objects each time from a blank (like it's shown in [this article](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/))? Does it affect the performance in any way?

*What is a prefered way of getting instance of CloudTable each time executing an operation against the table?*

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/629

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[CloudStorageAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudstorageaccount.aspx)

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

[CloudTableClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudtableclient.aspx)

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

Comment: So, what's is the prefered way to make table requests? Create all objects each time?

Comment: I think that would very much vary depending on the application goal/design, you're options are to either re-create and/or to make it thread safe by locking. each have it's pros and cons. I doubt there's a one-rule-fits all (but then I used to be a consultant :-) )

Answer (score 7):

1. Unfortunately, they are not thread safe
2. Fortunately, it doesn't matter at all:
   The communication is based on HTTP, which means no connection is reused and everytime the app just creates a new HTTP connection. So just recreate everything per thread. And I have tested even in one thread, recreating everything for each query just costs nothing more.

Comment: Be aware that if you use the clients too much without giving GC a chance to cleanup the connections, you'll run out of sockets.