# Is the Azure CloudTable class thread-safe in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, azure, azure-table-storage

Just like the .NET SDK for Azure storage, the Java version has a [CloudTable](http://dl.windowsazure.com/storage/javadoc/com/microsoft/azure/storage/table/CloudTable.html) class used for executing operations against a specific Azure Table.

And while it seems that the .NET implementation [isn't thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246720/is-azure-cloudtable-thread-safe), I can't find any definitive answer for Java. So is the Java version thread safe or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you've already seen the response to the issue you created on github https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/issues/38. Re-posting the answer for those who come across this question in the future.

> We do not make any thread-safety guarantees about our libraries. We also do not test them for thread-safety. Methods that are currently thread-safe may be thread-unsafe in future versions. Thank you for pointing this out to us. We will look into updating our documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The v12 of the Azure API [is said to be threadsafe](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-storage/announcing-the-azure-storage-v12-client-libraries/ba-p/1482394).

Comment: Only Azure Storage SDK